# How to compile Fortran 77 files in linux?

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, fortran

I need a compiler for Fortran 77 in linux.

Are there any free compilers out there that people use?

I've heard about g77, but I can't find the rpm or how to install it in linux.

Thanks!

Comment: What distribution? You could compile gcc from sources of course, but there are better ways...

Comment: See below: package on RedHat 4.1.2 is different than on Fedora.

Comment: ORACLE Solaris studio 12.4 is available too : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/t-eKoZDQUFM

Answer (score 20, accepted):

GCC's Fortran compiler name has changed: `g77` has been replaced by `gfortran`, which handles Fortran 95 and possibly more recent variants.

The package in Ubuntu is called `gfortran`:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

(or use synaptic)

The package in Fedora is called gfortran and is part of gcc, which you probably already have:

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

(or use pirut)

Similar searches should work for your distribution as well.

**Update:** On RedHat 4.1.2 the package seems to be called `gcc4-gfortran`.  Incidentally, you ought to be able to search for this with yum, and that may be the best answer to your question:

```
yum search "*fortran*"
```

Comment: i have redhat. i tried "sudo yum install g77" and also gfortran but it says no package g77/gfortran available. am i doing it wrong?

Comment: It's not called g77 for one thing.  I did a Google search for "Redhat 4.1.2 gfortran".  The package is apparently called "gcc4-gfortran".  Updating the answer.

Comment: g77 is not renamed gfortran. Those are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

For Amazon Linux:

```
 sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install gcc-gfortran
```

Answer (score 2):

"Quark" wrote in his answer that g77 is renamed gfortran. That is not correct.

g77 ang gfortran are different compilers. g77 is *replaced* by gfortran in the GNU compiler collection (GCC), it is not *renamed* gfortran.

gfortran is a modern Fortran compiler based on the g95 compiler. g77 is abandonware. They do not share codebase. Binary files and libraries are also not compatible between g77 and gfortran, as they use different ABIs.

g77 is the same compiler known as f2c (which can be downloaded from [Netlib](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/)), or more precisely a shell script called fc which called f2c and then cc on the output. All g77 did was to skip C as an intermediate language as it came with a speed penalty in the 1980s and early 1990s. f2c and g77 was written by the same man and are otherwise identical. With a modern CPU (long pipeline and branch prediction) and a modern C compiler (much better alias analysis), g77 gives you no advantage over the original f2c. gfortran, on the other hand, supports modern Fortran standards (Fortran 90, 95, 2003, and 2008) in addtion to the older Fortran 77 and Fortran 66 (aka FORTRAN IV), and is a clear improvement over g77 and f2c. It also generates faster code and gives us better error messages.

g77 is binary compatible with f2c, but not with gfortran. gfortran can be forced to assume g77 ABI by passing -ff2c. This compiler option should be avoided if possible as it degrades the performance of the Fortran code.

Comment: Hi didn't write that. He wrote GCC now has a compiler with different name which replaced g77. The accepted answer is correct.

Comment: It is correct now. It wasn't when I commented.

Answer (score 1):

There's http://www.g95.org/ that's available.

If I remember well GNU doesn't have a FORTRAN compiler but a FORTRAN preprocessor (or whatever the name for that is). It just translates your code to C and the compiles it with the C compiler. Of course performance becomes crap in the process.

However if you're using FORTRAN I assume it's a kind of computation project. If it's for free (not academic and not course related) you can get Intel FORTRAN compiler for free. In my experience it goes about 3-4 times faster than any free implementation.

Comment: where can i get the *Free* copy of intel fortran for linux? I am having difficulty finding the free version on google.

Comment: I think he might be referring to the free 30 day evaluation license.

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-development/

Comment: Also, gfortran is a full compiler: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran

Comment: If you're doing non-commercial development, the Intel compiler is a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc-fortran` is the package name for `Fortran` compiler for `openSUSE 11.x`.

```
linux-y3pi: # zypper what-provides gcc-fortran
Loading repository data...                                                                                                                                                        
Reading installed packages...
S | Name        | Type    | Version | Arch   | Repository             
--+-------------+---------+---------+--------+------------------------
i | gcc-fortran | package | 4.5-4.2 | x86_64 | openSUSE-11.3-Oss      
i | gcc-fortran | package | 4.5-4.2 | x86_64 | openSUSE-11.3 11.3-1.82
v | gcc-fortran | package | 4.5-4.2 | i586   | openSUSE-11.3-Oss      
[1]+  Done                    yast2
linux-y3pi: #
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps and worked!

1. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. add this text in that file (`/etc/apt/sources.list`):

   ```
   deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
   deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
   deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
   deb-src http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
   ```
3. Save file
4. Open terminal, type : `sudo apt-get install fort77`

Answer (score 0):

The means for getting software installed is distribution-specific. For example, in Ubuntu9, I would kick up Synaptic and do a search for Fortran or g77 (apt-get can also be used).

The other distributions I know little about although I've heard of yum and yast for (I think but I'm not sure) RedHat and Suse.

If it's not available through your standard package installer, you'll have to find another solution, such as:

- using a different Fortran; or
- building it from the source.

That second method sounds ominous but it's really not (other than ensuring you have the right dependencies). The configure/make/install process that most source packages follow makes it remarkably easy to do in a cross-distribution manner.

Some RPMs can be found [here](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc-g77). The GNU software is available [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/) or you may want to check out their [mirrors](http://www.gnu.org/prep/ftp.html) for a faster site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Netbeans and make c&c++ project and make add Fortran with new .f90 file and use Netbeans tools to run and debug .
before that you must install gcc and gfortran packages .

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Red Hat distributions (and those based on it) have gfortran included, but it is an option when you do the installation, so it seems probable that your system was set up without gfortran.  If you have installation media, I think you should be able to install gfortran from there.

Otherwise, to get the proper gfortran RPM for your system, I suggest the [related rpmfind page](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc-gfortran).

Once you get gfortran installed, I think the "-std=legacy" (quotes mine) should allow an F77 compile to work.